# Can I use experimental data from one experiment in another?

Tags: anova, experiment-design

I ran an experiment with a simple 2 x 2 factorial design. Subjects were high school students.  Factor 1 = school (school 1, school 2).  Factor 2 = group (treatment/control).  N = 322, split quite evenly by cell. I found significant mean differences by group and no significant differences by school or group*school.

Now I would like to compare students with teachers.  My primary interest is in two factors: group (treatment/control; and subject type (teacher/student).  It's not practical for me to get a fresh sample of students.  Can I compare the student data I already have to the teacher data? I'd like to run a simple 2 x 2 ANOVA with group and subject type as IVs.  What criticisms would you make of this approach?

I hear you ask, "why not just add subject type as another factor to the initial 2x2, so I have a 3 x 2?"  Two reasons (please tell me if they are not good):

1. I'd like to ignore the school factor as I found no significant differences among students by school. Also, descriptive stats for my teacher data show no big differences by school.  So my hypothesis is that I can ignore this factor.  Also, teachers are from 10 different schools so my cell sizes would be very small (although I guess I'd just be introducing the factor as a control, not as a factor of interest so maybe that doesn't matter).
2. I have N = 322 students but only N = 200 teachers.  I'd like to randomly sample my student data to get N = 200 so as to match cell sizes and increase power.

Comment: From your description it sounds like you don't have a crossed factorial design, but a design that has nested elements.  Students, nested within teachers, nested within schools.  If this is the case, you need to take that nesting into account when you perform your analysis.